# Inner class in interface that must be implemented by the "implementor"

Tags: java

I have this interface:

```
public interface ISectionListItem {
    public int getLayoutId();
    public void setProps(View view, int position);  
}
```

But i want all the classes who implements this interface be forces to have a static class inside them. I thought of:

```
 public interface ISectionListItem {
    public int getLayoutId();
    public void setProps(View view, int position);

    static class ViewHolder {};
}
```

But that dosn't force the classes to "add unimplemented inner classes". Anyway to accomplish this? Is it even possible?

Thanks :)

Comment: Surely the point of an interface is so that the implementor can do what they want - using a static class or not - if you need them to have a static class you need to show more of how the interface is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible by the nature of interfaces. An interface defines the public behavior of *objects*; if a class implements an interface, that means that all *instances* of that class obey the contract defined by the interface. For this reason interfaces can't contain static members. (There's an exception to this rule, but at this point you shouldn't care about that.)

Be careful of your terminology: static member classes are not inner classes. Static member classes are like normal classes, except that they live in a different namespace. Static member classes are *not* members of the instances of the containing class, just as any static class member is not part of the "instance template". An inner class is by definition not static.

So, why can't we declare a genuine (i.e. non-static) inner class in an interface? That's because in an interface you can only define the behavior of objects, not how they are composed. The whole point (and beauty) of interfaces is that they separate the behavior ("*what* does it do") from the implementation ("*how* is it done"). For that reason you can't declare inner classes in an interface, just as you can't declare fields in an interface.

I don't know what you're trying to do, but you might want to try the following. Let's call your original interface `MyInterface`.

1. Define an extra interface `SomeType`
2. Have your inner class implement `SomeType`
3. Declare a method like `public SomeType getInnerClassInstance()` (a terrible method name) in `MyInterface`

Note that `MyInterface` instances aren't forced to actually return an instance of an inner class as a result of `getInnerClassInstance()`. This is a nice thing, because you're not bound to a specific implementation.

Answer (score 8):

The point of an interface is that you're defining a contract, not an implementation. If you really need to have an instance then you'd want to do something like

```
 public ViewHolder getViewHolder();
```

and define a viewholder interface. Again, the idea is that you're not creating an implementation, you're expressing a contract.

Answer (score 1):

You can't force someone to create an inner class.

Depending on what you want to do your best best is probably adding a method `getViewHolder()` to the interface and create another interface which specifies the behaviour of a ViewHolder.